# Google api redirect uri issue while reading google sheet from java

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I am using oauth2 google drive API to read data from a google sheet in Java.
I have an working sample on my local machine. But when I deploy it on the remote server, at the time of authentication the API returns a URL which is to be opened in browser.
The URL is like below :

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=online&approval_prompt=auto&client_id=my.client.id&redirect_uri=http://**localhost:58305**/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

Obviously this URL will not open on remote server as there is no localhost.

My google developers console configuration while generating oauth client id:

1. Application type : Web Application or Other
2. Authorized JavaScript origins : My remote server origin
3. Authorized redirect URIs : My remote server page

The authentication gets successfully done on my local machine when the Application type is **Other**.
The same when deployed on remote server fails to authenticate because of the **localhost** string inside the authentication URL.

On the other hand when the application type is **Web Application** it gives me an error page on both localhost and remote server which has error like below even when I have added proper origins in the above options:

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:59363/Callback, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/my.client.id?project=my.project.id to update the authorized redirect URIs.
```

I tried multiple options with the redirect URIs. But it gives same error.

1. Is there any setting in the authentication where we can change the
   fix the **localhost:59363** part ?
2. Is **application type : web application** correct when I have to
   deploy this on production server as **application type : other** is
   for **installed** apps ?

Comment: I just posted a question about this topic: "Code Servlet to Read/Write Google Sheets Data" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49604035/code-servlet-to-read-write-google-sheets-data . Would you mind having a chat about how you were able to implement your solution?

Comment: I am facing the same issue while using google drive api. Everything works fine on localhost with application type : Other.When published on iis gives "Error: redirect_uri_mismatch".When I use application type : web application gives "Error: redirect_uri_mismatch" in local as well.Tried many options with redirect uris but still no luck.Searching for solution from last week.Can someone tell what should be the redirect uri that should be provided ? Cuurently I am using  http://localhost:62283 as my url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the redirect uri same as the one which you have provided in google console in your java code.

Take a look at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#web_server_applications

```
    @Override
  protected String getRedirectUri(HttpServletRequest req) throws ServletException, IOException {
    GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(req.getRequestURL().toString());
    url.setRawPath("/oauth2callback");
    return url.build();
  }
```

You build your redirect url. Currently you are sending that as localhost:58305/Callback

update it and it should work

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong API credential type.

For your project go to: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials and choose an OAUTH2 credential (client ID of type: **OTHER**).

Comment: I have used "other" but still I am facing the same issue as stated above.