# Code Servlet to Read/Write Google Sheets Data

Tags: java, servlets, google-client

I'm writing a Servlet that reads and writes data in a Google Sheets doc. The doc is owned or shared with the account of the user hitting the Servlet, so they must authenticate using OAuth2.

I wrote a commandline (Java) application that works to get access using the Google API Client Library. I generated a client ID of Application Type "other". Then I wrapped that application in a `Servlet extends HttpServlet` (running in standalone Jetty). The flow stalls at

```
Credential credential =
    new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver())
    .authorize("user");
```

because the `authorize()` call outputs to STDERR (ie. Jetty log) the authorization URL and listens on a socket until it hears a valid authenticated/authorized token. Even if the Servlet could catch the auth URL from STDERR it couldn't send it back to the user for clicking, because 1> it's stalled at `authorize()` and 2> it can send back only a single HTML response.

I'm trying to follow Google's documentation [Google API Client Libraries Java / Web server applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#web_server_applications), but the supplied code is for Calendar and the doc doesn't explain how to use it in a Servlet (or in anything else). That doc also links to a [Google Identity Platform / 
Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) doc, but it starts off offering to document a Java project then provides code and guidance only for PHP, Python, Ruby, HTTP/REST. There are bits and pieces of guidance in blogs, other Google docs, other products, other OAuth2 targets, across many versions of the Google API and of OAuth - incomprehensible.

Where can I find good docs of the implementation procedure, especially with sample code? An example project? Or just directions for porting the commandline application to a Servlet? Thank you.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue as getting localhost, which works fine on my local system but not on server

Comment: Shubham, is there a page or online hosted project that shows what you've implemented, even though it has that specific problem?