# Google api redirect issue when deploy spring boot on heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, google-sheets-api, google-oauth

I'm making an application with spring boot. It takes data from the Google sheet API. I follow along with this tutorial and it works well with my local machine.
tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8yJrQk9ShPg&t=172s

After I deployed the application on Heroku I face the same issue as this post
[Google api redirect uri issue while reading google sheet from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45952624/google-api-redirect-uri-issue-while-reading-google-sheet-from-java?fbclid=IwAR1nt5wmj4Vq-AgGwvMfd9pQYRA-KONXQ8p62VJBaaC_3wgpbFpnNd_jrjY)

I try to follow along by

1. Add **https://{my-app}.herokuapp.com/** to Authorized domains
2. Create Google API credential with **Web Application** type and set Authorized to redirect URIs to my Heroku domain **https://{my-app}.herokuapp.com/**
3. Download it and replace the one that works when running locally.

```
    {
      "web": {
        "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "project_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "redirect_uris": [
          "https://{my-app}.herokuapp.com/"
        ]
      }
    }
```

4. Create new class **OAuth2Callback extends AbstractAppEngineAuthorizationCodeCallbackServlet**

```
    @Override
    protected String getRedirectUri(HttpServletRequest req) throws ServletException, IOException {
        GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl("https://{my-app}.herokuapp.com");
        url.setRawPath("/Callback");
        return url.build();
    }
```

5. Deploy to Heroku

After these steps log on Heroku show the same as localhost when running the first time

```
Please open the following address in your browser:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:45200/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly
```

I copy and open it in my browser. Then it throw **Error: redirect_uri_mismatch** back because redirect_uri is still localhost.
I expected that redirect_uri should be changed to https://{my-app}.herokuapp.com but no.
I also try to change localhost:42500 to https://{my-app}.herokuapp.com manually in the provided URL and it still throws the same error.

Please help me correct my authentication configuration. Thanks.

- This is my first post, sorry for my bad grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution.
Actually, in my application, I should have implement **"Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications"** which use service account's credentials instead of **"Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications"**
Link : https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Here is step

1. Create Google service account from the same project https://console.developers.google.com/ then download and place at resources folder
2. Change get credential method from using 
   ***credential = AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow, VerificationCodeReceiver) (example https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/)*** to GoogleCredential, please see below

```
    public static Credential getCredential() throws IOException {
        if (credential == null) {
            InputStream is = GoogleSheetsCredential.class
              .getResourceAsStream("/sheets-service-account.json");
            credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(is)
              .createScoped(Collections.singleton(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS));
        }
        return credential;
    }
```

Then I deploy to Heroku and it works!!!
Hope this help if someone face the same issue with me.

Here is tutorial reference : https://techxlore.com/google-sheets-api-service-account/

Comment: did you deploy your google service accout json file on heroku explicitly?

Comment: @RenceAbi I use automatic deploy feature on Heroku.

Comment: There is a hack! you dont need to deploy your key in version control. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62326500/how-to-use-google-api-credentials-on-heroku-in-spring-boot-project