# How to use Google API credentials on Heroku in Spring Boot Project

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, heroku, google-api

I have followed [official](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/elishaterada/heroku-google-application-credentials-buildpack) documentation to achieve this. But I'm still facing issue. I'm doing spring boot project. below is my code,

```
@Configuration
public class FirebaseConfiguration {

   // database url, other urls
   // other codes...

   @Value(value = "classpath:google-credentials.json")
   private Resource gservicesConfig;

  @Bean
  public FirebaseApp provideFirebaseOptions() throws IOException {
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream((gservicesConfig.getInputStream())))
        .setDatabaseUrl(databaseUrl)
        .setStorageBucket(storageUrl)
        .build();

    return FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
  }

}
```

Also i have added Configs as per official documentation as below

1.Create Config Vars key GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS and paste the content of service account credential JSON file as is.
2.Create a key under Config Vars GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and set a value as google-credentials.json.

Added `https://github.com/elishaterada/heroku-google-application-credentials-buildpack.git` buildpack as well. But in logs im getting below issue.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [google-credentials.json] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at com.read.bible.service.config.FirebaseConfiguration.provideFirebaseOptions(FirebaseConfiguration.java:35) ~[classes!/:na]
at com.read.bible.service.config.FirebaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$93cb42d.CGLIB$provideFirebaseOptions$0(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Actually It is not a real answer in my point of view.

I haven't pushed google service account json key in version control.

I have followed only the first step (Removed `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` from config vars) which was provided by [official](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/buyersight/heroku-google-application-credentials-buildpack) heroku document and modifed in my configuration as below

**Modified:**

1. Directly pointing `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS` which is json key and added in config vars on heroku setting
2. Received value as `String` instead of `Resource`

In my Configuration Class,

```java
@Configuration
public class FirebaseConfiguration {

   // database url, other urls
   // other codes...

   @Value("${GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS}")
   private String gservicesConfig;

  @Bean
  public FirebaseApp provideFirebaseOptions() throws IOException {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(gservicesConfig.toString());
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonObject.toString().getBytes());
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream((is)))
        .setDatabaseUrl(databaseUrl)
        .setStorageBucket(storageUrl)
        .build();

    return FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
  }

}
```